# Mongo query is slow using C# driver but fast using mongo shell

Tags: c#, mongodb, query-optimization, database

I got very weird problem with MongoDB C# driver. I have a very simple query and I have a correct index for that query. When I run the query using MongoChef (and using the shell) I get the results in 22ms
But when my app runs the same query it takes about 2.5mins to return answer (this is not due to network problems).

I have checked in db.currentOp() and I saw that the op is indeed taking about 2.5 mins to finish and the query is the same as the one I ran manually and the execution plan do use the index.
Any idea? 
Thanks

P.S
The problem is not with the size of the result set! I have tested with results set that have 0 results, 21 results and 600,000 results and in all of them the results was horrible! (above 2m for only 21 results which in the shell takes no time!)

```
{
  "inprog": [
       {
         "opid" : 53214,
         "active" : true,
         "secs_running" : 174,
         "microsecs_running" : 174085497,
         "op" : query,
         "ns" : db.collection,
         "query" : {{$query : {ParentId: 55, IsDeleted : false}},
              {$orderby : {_id : -1}}},
         "planSummary": IXSCAN {_id : 1},
         "client" : ip:port,
         "desc" : conn121254,
         "threadId" : 0x1234567,
         "connectionId" : 1254651,
         "locks" : {
             "Global" : r,
             "MMAPV1Journal" : r,
             "Database" : r,
             "Collection" : R
         },
         "waitingForLock" : false,
         "numYields" : 46963,
         "lockStats" : {
             "Global" : {acquireCount : { r : 93928}},
             "MMAPV1Journal" : {acquireCount : { r : 46964} , acquireWaitCount : { r : 2 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r : 2 } },
             "Database" : {acquireCount : { r : 46964}},
             "Collection" : {acquireCount : { r : 46964}}
         }
       }
   ]
}
```

And the query that is running great on the shell (22ms)

```
db.collection.find({ParentId : 55, IsDeleted : false}).sort({_id : 1})
```

C# code example :

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://MongosServer01:27017,MongosServer02:27017,MongosServer03:27017,MongosServer04:27017");
var collection = client.GetServer().GetDatabase("db").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");
var cursor = collection.Find(Query.And(Query.EQ("ParentId" , 55),Query.EQ("IsDeleted" , false))).SetSortOrder("_id").SetLimit(20);
```

Comment: Can you post the C# and shell code for the query, as well as the explain? If you have a large result set one likely difference is that the `mongo` shell only iterates the first 20 results by default, while your application code may be iterating the complete result set.

Comment: I cant really post my code, I will post my explain plain shortly. see the further explaination i gave and you will see why I do not think it is about the result set or any iteration (TL;DR : I tried it on very small result sets)

Comment: Unless, you don't post your C# code, it's hard to pinpoint problem or make any judgement.

Comment: Added the part of the code that handles this query, nothing speical

Comment: I have the exact same problem with Java now. I see a slow query log from the mongodb logs , that took 15 seconds. I simply copy paste it to the shell and it runs instantly. Then I try the same query with Java again , and again it takes 15 seconds... I'm out of ideas . (both java app and shell are running on the same machine. this has nothing to do with network)

Answer (score 0):

I think your differences is related to the amount Doc's each method bring .
MongoChef has some default around 50 , in your code you you probably bring all your doc's .

I hope you will find it useful

Thanks

Comment: It is not related to the amount of docs, i tried it with queries that returned no docs and on queries that returned 20 docs, which in code took about 2.5m and in the shell it took no time (again I repeat, i checked in current op to see that the C# generated query is as the one i wrote in the shell), BTW, Toda raba eli!